Conflict between reledmac and tcolorbox
I use XeLaTeX to compile for a Sanskrit "critical edition" book with the documentclass as book. For that, I use reledmac package with the following code in the preamble:
\usepackage[series={A,B,C},noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup, parapparatus]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage[parapparatus]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{twocol}

I also use tcolorbox package to get a nice box around the quotes. And, the code for it is
\newtcolorbox{boxquote}[1][]{%
        colback=yellow!12,
        colframe=black!6,
        notitle,
        sharp corners,
        borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{red!80!black},
        enhanced,
        breakable,
}

The issues I was facing is:

The quoted part came out of the box and looked weird.
The whole boxquote was considered as only one line by the reledmac

Here to note that, if there were footnote entries that were created using \edtext{}{\Afootnote{}} inside the boxquote, they were displayed at the bottom with the same line number for all such entries.
As I searched for the solution for the issue of "quoted part coming out of the box," I found out that the issue occurs because the boxquote was present inside \pstart and \pend commands as
\beginnumbering
\pstart 
Some text having edtext \edtext{ABCD}{\Afootnote{ABD F.}}
\begin{boxquote}
Some text
\end{boxquote}
Some text having edtext \edtext{xyz}{\Afootnote{XY C.}}
\pend
\endnumbering

So I changed it to
\beginnumbering
\pstart 
Some text having edtext \edtext{ABCD}{\Afootnote{ABD F.}}
\pend
\begin{boxquote}
Some text
\end{boxquote}
\pstart 
Some text having edtext \edtext{xyz}{\Afootnote{XY C.}}
\pend
\endnumbering

This solved my problem as the quotes can be seen inside the box. However, for the quotes having \edtext{}{\Afootnote{}} inside the boxquote, the compiler threw the following error:
! Package reledmac Error: \edtext outside numbered paragraph (\pstart ... \pend).

To solve this error, I used \pstart and \pend inside the boxquote as
\beginnumbering
\pstart 
Some text having edtext \edtext{ABCD}{\Afootnote{ABD F.}}
\pend
\begin{boxquote}
\pstart 
Some text having edtext \edtext{PQRS}{\Afootnote{PSQ G.}}
\pend
\end{boxquote}
\pstart 
Some text having edtext \edtext{xyz}{\Afootnote{XY C.}}
\pend
\endnumbering

Because of this, the error was resolved, however, I got into two problems

The footnotes present in the boxquote disappeared at the bottom.
Now the lines inside the boxquote got the numbers, however, they were indented as compared to the other line numbers outside the boxquote.

Now I am not getting the reledmac footnotes that were created using \edtext{}{\Afootnote{}} inside the boxquotes.
My further searches didn't help me. I shall be thankful for your help.

As explained in the reledmac handbook, no special command (that is especially command dealing with vertical space) should be used inside \pstart...\pend. But you may call them in optional argument of \pstart and \pend.
Please also next time provide a full mwe.

Thanks @Maïeul. I just edited my post where there are no extra blank lines present in the code now. There are also no extra blank lines in my original code. I am sorry for not being able to present MWE here. At the same time, I wish you could help further. Thanks.

Sorry, but my time is precious, especially regarding latex. So I can't help you without MWE.
